# Adding a parameter to a JS function

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm working on a FullCalendar; there are 9-10 events everyday in it and now I have to create the ability to delete an event.

This is the code:

```
eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {               
                $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                var imgName=event.image;
                document.getElementById('imageDiv').innerHTML = '<img src='+imgName+' onerror=".'this.style.display="none"'." class=".'img-responsive'." alt=".''." >';
                $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
                $('#eventid').html(event.id);
                $('#startTime').html(moment(event.start).format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
                $('#endTime').html(moment(event.end).format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
                $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
                $('#fullCalModal').modal();

                 return false;
            }
```

I get the events list with this:

```
echo events: [
                ";
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo "
                {
                    id: '".$row['id']."',
                    title: '".$row['title']."',
                    image: 'assets/uploads/".$row['image']."',
                    description: '<p>".$row['description']."</p>',                  
                    start: '".$row['start']."',
                    end: '".$row['end']."',
                    url: '".$row['url']."',
                    color: '".$row['color']."',
                    allDay: true
                },";    
        } ;
        echo "
            ]
```

And now, when a user clicks on an event, the modal should popup with additional details and a button for deleting the event. 
This is handled with:

```
function modalEvents(){
echo "  
<div id='fullCalModal' class='modal fade'>
...
<p id='eventid'></p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='modal-footer'>
            <a href='javascript:EliminateEvent(\"event.id\")' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' role='button'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-trash'></i>Brisanje rezervacije</a>
```

However... the problem is that I get the actual ID value in , however, I'm having a hard time getting the same result in the link, the javascript:EliminateEvent() 
Is there a way that I could get as a result

```
<a href='javascript:EliminateEvent(123)>
```

instead of

```
<a href='javascript:EliminateEvent(event.id)>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the string "event.Id" in the function parameter is because you are actually asking PHP to do that. When you click on the event you could set the event id with JavaScript like you did with all the details. Like: href="javascript:EliminateEvent(" + event.id + ")"

Comment: Nope, still no luck. 
If I add event.id as you suggested, for some reason, the modal popup won't show up at all. I've also tried to get the a href line totally out of PHP and have it as a plain HTML code, still, everything I enter into the EliminateEvents brackets will show up as a string :(

Comment: You don't have to use php to build the modal's html, let the modal there alone empty of content, and then fill it with pure javascript on the full calanendar click event.